# Why are grails plugin assets not copied in the right place when packaging as a war?

Tags: grails

I am using the [Calendar Plaugin](http://www.grails.org/Calendar+Plugin) in my application and on local testing it works great. It loads its assets from

> http://localhost:8080/YYYYYY/plugins/calendar-1.2.1/js/calendar.js

However, when deployed as a war the gsp file looks for the assets at

> http://XXXX/YYYYYY/js/calendar.js (i.e. no /plugins/calendar-1.2.1/)

and fails. My question is why is the packaged file looking for the plugin assets in the root when deployed as a war when they are packaged into the plugins/calendar-1.2.1/ sub directory? If they are looked up in the root should some code be copying them that is not configured or working properly?

Comment: What version of grails? Are you using the resources framework?

Comment: 2.0.1, and I am not sure how would I check if I am using the resources framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/resources)

Basically if you have the resources plugin installed and are using any of the `<r:require` and `<r:layoutResources` tags in your layouts and views you are using the framework.

The plugin handles resources such as css, javascript, images and their dependencies and I believe the plugin is installed by default in 2.0.1 so it might be worth looking into it as the missing link in your problem.